# how to browse website without showing what website i use to my service provider

Tags: facebook, browser, server, service-provider

My **internet service provider** gives us to **free facebook access** without data usage.zero data usage for  video,live and all others related to facebook server.so are there any method to **browse other website without knowing them what i use** and show them i only use facebook server.

Comment: No there is not.